# Error installing gem: Couldn't reserve space for cygwin's heap, Win32 error 487

Tags: ruby, rubygems, devkit

I'm trying to install `win32-api` gem on my machine and I'm facing some issues when building native extensions:

```
$ gem install win32-api --no-ri --rdoc
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
C:\Programs\dev_kit\bin\make.exe: *** Couldn't reserve space for cygwin's heap, Win32 error 0
ERROR:  Error installing win32-api:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        c:/Programs/ruby/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for strncpy_s()... no
creating Makefile

make
      0 [main] us 0 init_cheap: VirtualAlloc pointer is null, Win32 error 487
AllocationBase 0x0, BaseAddress 0x60E90000, RegionSize 0x170000, State 0x10000
C:\Programs\dev_kit\bin\make.exe: *** Couldn't reserve space for cygwin's heap, Win32 error 0
```

This problem happens when installing any gem that tries to compile a native extension, like json or win32-api, for instance.

I already tried to change the size of virtual memory of this machine, but it didn't work.

My configuration:

- Ruby version: 1.8.7p371
- Gem version: 1.8.24
- Bash 3.1.0
- DevKit 4.5.2
- Windows 7 x64

Comment: If it's not too disruptive for future people dropping by this question, try a reboot first. I ended up uninstalling/re-installing and coming to the same error... 1 reboot, all fixed. Another similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18502999/git-extensions-win32-error-487-couldnt-reserve-space-for-cygwins-heap-win32/31970708#31970708

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I was facing the exact same issue and after making a lot of searches and many different tries, this is what fixed it for me:

1. Download `rebase` from http://www.tishler.net/jason/software/rebase/ (download the latest *.exe version) and run it.
2. Fire up a Prompt ("Run as administrator") and go to your `dev-kit` folder (for instance, mine was `C:\Programs\dev_kit`)
3. While in the dev-kit folder, run `devkitvars.bat` to add devkit to the path.
4. Now do a `cd bin` (it got me to `C:\Programs\dev_kit\bin`) and from there run:

   ```
   rebase -b 0x30000000 msys-1.0.dll
   ```

Try to install the gems again. Instead of seeing an error message, now you should see `Building native extensions. This could take a while...` and it will hang for a while there.

Your gem should be successfully installed after a couple of minutes/seconds. No more headaches :)

Comment: For me, in devkit bin directory, the administrator propmt doesn't recognize 'rebase'...

Comment: After running this, the original problem went away, but then I started seeing errors containing "*** target pattern contains no '%'". The easiest fix I found was to downgrade RubyGems using `gem update --system 2.3.0`. Details [here](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues/977).

Comment: This throws errors about `cygwin1.dll is missing fromyour computer` when trying to run rebase...