# Chef/Knife running two environments on same machine

Tags: environment, knife, chef-infra

We have a series of cookbooks that are common across many environments. Up until recently, they've always been on different machines. Now we have a requirement that we need to run the same series of cookbooks across two environment files on the same machine.

What is the best practice here for doing this? Simply calling:

```
knife winrm %server% chef-client -m -x %user% -P %pass% -E %environment%
```

Is that the same as:

```
Knife node edit %server%
```

And changing the environment there? We need to be able to do command line switching of environments. Please advise, TIA!

Comment: Two client registrations? Run the second client as follows "chef-client -c /path/to/alternative/client/config/client.rb". I'd be interested in a better solution!!

Comment: Have you seen [knife-flip](https://github.com/jonlives/knife-flip)?

Comment: knife-flip is exactly what i need, thank you @sethvargo!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tool you are looking for is [knife-flip](https://github.com/jonlives/knife-flip) by John Cowie from Etsy:

```
$ knife node flip mynode.foo.com myenv [--preview]
```

Comment: Went to install knife-flip and get an cygwin heap error on my Windows7 box. Just wanted to add that this can be fixed using:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19259272/error-installing-gem-couldnt-reserve-space-for-cygwins-heap-win32-error-487