# The Git Bash console crashes on open

Tags: windows, git, bash, crash, cygwin

I have been using Git Bash version 1.9.5 on Windows 8 successfully for a few weeks. This morning it stopped working. Every time I open Git Bash it shows up for a second and then crashes. I have searched everywhere for solutions; every forum says to uninstall Git and re-install a newer version. I have the newest version. I have re-installed Git and restarted my computer tons of times. I have tried opening Git from program files, from the console and from a few different shortcuts. I don't know what else to do.

Below is a screenshot of the split second the console window is open before it crashes.

[image: Git crash error message]

Comment: You need to change the Virtual Memory allocation of Windows, look at these steps : http://www.microchip.com/forums/FindPost/523439

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git Extensions: Win32 error 487: Couldn't reserve space for cygwin's heap, Win32 error 0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18502999/git-extensions-win32-error-487-couldnt-reserve-space-for-cygwins-heap-win32)

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue which resolved after deleting all the configuration files on home directory `C:\Users\<username>`. These included .bash_history, .bashrc, .bash_profile, .bash_aliases, .gitconfig, .git-credentials, .minttyrc and .npmrc. After restoring them one by one and opening git bash, I found the culprit to be .minttyrc line `Term=xterm-256color` I removed this line and it solved the problem.

Comment: Have an upvote. Win10 and just upgraded from 2.13.something to 2.16.1.4 and had the same problem. Commenting out the Term line fixed it.

Comment: Same here; Windows 10.0.16299.248, Git 2.16.1.windows.4

Comment: Upvote! For me, I removed zsh-related code from `.bashrc` and the problem was resolved.

Answer (score -1):

You need to change the Virtual Memory allocation of Windows :

- Go to **Control Panel/System and Security/System** then **Advanced Systems Setting**.
- On the **Advanced** tab, click on the performance **Settings** button.
- Select **Advanced** tab, and click on the **Change** button
- Enter a custom size value as follows:

  - *Initial Size (MB)* = Currently Allocated (shown at the bottom)
  - *Maximum Size (MB)* = Recommended (shown at the bottom)
- Click on **Set** button, click **OK**, **reboot PC** and enjoy !

Comment: Didn't work for me. I have 64 gigs of physical memory, more than 48 gigs is unallocated. It seems remarkable that any part of Cygwin would need more memory than I have available.

Comment: This link has a more complete and thoughtful answers. As far as I can tell, this is just a bug in cygwin (or ssh-agent), which expects a particular, constant virtual address to be available.  When it's not, it falls over.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18502999/git-extensions-win32-error-487-couldnt-reserve-space-for-cygwins-heap-win32