# Git Bash unable to allocate heap in Windows 7 (32 bit)

Tags: msysgit, git-bash

I have installed Git **1.9.5** in my Windows 7 (32 bit) machine and it installed properly. I was able to clone and checkout working copy from the remote server without any trouble. 
However whenever I open Git Bash it shows this error in the command prompt:

> C:\Program Files\Git\bin\sh.exe: *** 1. unable to allocate heap
>   0x10060000, heap
>   _chunk_size 268435456, pid 8260, Win32 error 0
>
> 0 [main] sh.exe" 9072 sync_with_child: child 8260(0x1A4) died before
>   ini alization with status code 0x1    1547 [main] sh.exe" 9072
>   sync_with_child: *** child state waiting for longjump
>
> sh.exe": fork: Resource temporarily unavailable

I get same error whenever I am trying to execute `git pull` command. 
I tried to rebase the **msys-1.0.dll** file following [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18502999/git-extensions-win32-error-487-couldnt-reserve-space-for-cygwins-heap-win32) but didn't help. Would be great if someone can help me sort it out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It doesn't seem like git error but like a windows error.

Comment: What other apps are running at the same time?  How much memory does your machine have?

Comment: My memory is 4GB, utilizing 1.68 GB at this moment. Mainly running Chrome and IE browsers right now. But some security softwares also running like ESCORT/NASCA @Chilledrat

Comment: From what I remember of 32bit Windows, it doesn't play well with more than 3GB, unless something has changed since the last time I used it, which wouldn't surprise me.   Does windows report the full 4GB (right-click on "Computer" either on the start menu or desktop icon and select properties.  The difference alone is unlikely to be enough given your utilization, but were you perhaps also running an IDE when you ran git?  Some IDEs can use a lot of RAM, especially with plugins installed.  I hope you understand I'm just trying to cover all the bases.

Comment: Does [this thread at the msysgit github](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/issues/268) help you at all?

Comment: When I run Eclipse IDE the memory utilization goes up to 2.48 GB. My configuration shows 4 GB (3.43 GB usable). I tried running the git bash keeping memory usage low but result is same. Is that link suggests changing the values of gitconfig file ? I haven't tried that yet. Its not very clear to me.

Comment: Sorry, it's not clear to me either, it just seemed like something that might help.  To be honest I don't use Windows much for development, but when I do I use [SourceTree](https://www.atlassian.com/software/sourcetree/overview) for git access.  It's a GUI but also has command line access built in.  My windows box is running 64-bit Win7 and only has 4GB but will happily run NetBeans or Eclipse and sourceTree (YMMV.)  It's Possibly worth giving it a shot just to get you over this hump while you wait for a permanent solution for msysgit.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort :) I actually downloaded source tree today but couldn't explore it much yet. Will definitely give a try. Have you tried eclipse's built in git plugin from Project->right click->Team ? It looks pretty rich to me as  a gui client.