# Aptana Studio 3 crashing - new error

Tags: memory, crash, aptana

I suddently started getting the following error when I start the Aptana Studio 3 terminal. The error might be obvious to those folks more familiar with languages where memory allocation is done manually, but it beats me. Here is the error:

```
0 [main] us 0 init_cheap: VirtualAlloc pointer is null, Win32 error 487
AllocationBase 0x684A0000, BaseAddress 0x68570000, RegionSize 0x4000, State 0x1000
C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\sh.exe : *** couldn't reserve space for
cygwin's heap, Win32 error 0
```

My OS is Windows 10 64 bits (I installed Windows 10 awhile back, it is not a new install)

I have already uninstalled and installed the program. Any piece of advice besides buying a mac? :)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

easier than I thought - rebooting does the job. There is an excellent response here (same problem with some other cygwin program, but not aptana studio 3)

[Git Extensions: Win32 error 487: Couldn't reserve space for cygwin's heap, Win32 error 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18502999/git-extensions-win32-error-487-couldnt-reserve-space-for-cygwins-heap-win32)

Explanation of the problem goes: Cygwin uses persistent shared memory sections, which can on occasion become corrupted.

Click on the link to know more :)