# git push fatal: Could not read from remote repository

Tags: git, ssh, cygwin, heap-memory

I want to git push, but...

Here is the error:

```
C:\Sites\workspace\sample_app1>git push
      0 [main] us 0 init_cheap: VirtualAlloc pointer is null, Win32 error 487
AllocationBase 0x0, BaseAddress 0x68570000, RegionSize 0x460000, State 0x10000
C:\RailsInstaller\Git\bin\ssh.exe: *** Couldn't reserve space for cygwin's heap, Win32 error 0

fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What OS are you using and what version of git?

Comment: windows10 , git version 1. 9. 4

Comment: Are you using the x64 bit version of git?

Comment: I'm using x32 bit.

Comment: [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18502999/git-extensions-win32-error-487-couldnt-reserve-space-for-cygwins-heap-win32)

Answer (score 0):

As noted, [that is a Win32 error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24406417/6309) that can be fixed with:

```
rebase.exe -b 0x50000000 msys-1.0.dll
```

But that is pre-Git 2.0 (2015), and **[msys2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35099458/6309)**.
Any recent [Git for Windows 2.x (32 and 64 bits)](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases) would avoid that issue.