# Installing Puma on windows VirtualAlloc pointer is null

Tags: ruby, rubygems, cygwin, puma, virtualalloc

I did check the other issues and majority had problems with `OpenSSL`. I did try the solutions other mentioned with installing the `OpenSSL` but it didn't help.

I am getting the following error message when trying to install the `Puma` by `gem install puma`:

```
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
C:\DevKit\bin\make.exe: *** Couldn't reserve space for cygwin's heap, Win32 error 0
C:\DevKit\bin\make.exe: *** Couldn't reserve space for cygwin's heap, Win32 error 0
ERROR:  Error installing puma:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: C:/Bitnami/rubystack-2.2.6-0/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.7.1/ext/puma_http11
C:/Bitnami/rubystack-2.2.6-0/ruby/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20170308-12444-1rq3kcf.rb extconf.rb
checking for BIO_read() in -lcrypto... no
checking for BIO_read() in -llibeay32... no
creating Makefile

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  C:/Bitnami/rubystack-2.2.6-0/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.3.0/puma-3.7.1/mkmf.log

current directory: C:/Bitnami/rubystack-2.2.6-0/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.7.1/ext/puma_http11
make "DESTDIR=" clean
      0 [main] us 0 init_cheap: VirtualAlloc pointer is null, Win32 error 487
AllocationBase 0x0, BaseAddress 0x60E90000, RegionSize 0x3E0000, State 0x10000
C:\DevKit\bin\make.exe: *** Couldn't reserve space for cygwin's heap, Win32 error 0

current directory: C:/Bitnami/rubystack-2.2.6-0/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.7.1/ext/puma_http11
make "DESTDIR="
      0 [main] us 0 init_cheap: VirtualAlloc pointer is null, Win32 error 487
AllocationBase 0x0, BaseAddress 0x60E90000, RegionSize 0x3E0000, State 0x10000
C:\DevKit\bin\make.exe: *** Couldn't reserve space for cygwin's heap, Win32 error 0

make failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in C:/Bitnami/rubystack-2.2.6-0/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.7.1 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Bitnami/rubystack-2.2.6-0/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.3.0/puma-3.7.1/gem_make.out
```

**System Specs:**

- OpenSSL Version: `OpenSSL 1.0.2j  26 Sep 2016`
- Ruby Version: `ruby 2.3.3p222 (2016-11-21 revision 56859) [x64-mingw32]`
- OS: `Windows 10`
- Devkit: `installed`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated on this answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/18503369/2355163, a `reboot` of the PC solved the issue.