# Error while gem install rails in Windows 10

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, rubygems

Can you explain me what I should do? I've already done adding source of rubygems.org and gem update --system

```
C:\Ruby22>gem install rails
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
C:\Ruby22\devkit\bin\make.exe: *** Couldn't reserve space for cygwin's heap, 
Win32 error 0
C:\Ruby22\devkit\bin\make.exe: *** Couldn't reserve space for cygwin's heap, 
Win32 error 0
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

C:/Ruby22/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR=" clean
  0 [main] us 0 init_cheap: VirtualAlloc pointer is null, Win32 error 487
AllocationBase 0x0, BaseAddress 0x60E90000, RegionSize 0x390000, State 0x10000
C:\Ruby22\devkit\bin\make.exe: *** Couldn't reserve space for cygwin's heap, Win32 error 0

make "DESTDIR="
  0 [main] us 0 init_cheap: VirtualAlloc pointer is null, Win32 error 487
AllocationBase 0x0, BaseAddress 0x60E90000, RegionSize 0x390000, State 0x10000
C:\Ruby22\devkit\bin\make.exe: *** Couldn't reserve space for cygwin's heap, Win32 error 0

make failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in 
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/websocket-driver-0.6.5 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/extensions/x86-mingw32/2.2.0/websocket-driver-0.6.5/gem_make.out
```

I really want to be free from c9. Locaaall!!

Answer (score 0):

This is not issue with rails or rubygems.org . It is related to github. You are using old version of git.

[Here is solution for this.](https://confluence.atlassian.com/sourcetreekb/exectuing-git-generates-couldn-t-reserve-space-for-cygwin-s-heap-794364929.html)

Also you can look into explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18502999/git-extensions-win32-error-487-couldnt-reserve-space-for-cygwins-heap-win32/31970708#31970708).

Copied solution from link above:

Both [current Cygwin](https://github.com/mirror/cygwin/blob/master/winsup/cygwin/cygheap.cc) and the [new version of MSYS](https://github.com/git-for-windows/msys2-runtime/blob/develop/winsup/cygwin/cygheap.cc) - MSYS2 - already have different logic in place, which is hopefully more robust. It's only old versions of Git for Windows which have been still built using the old broken MSYS system.

Resolution:

Install [Git for Windows 2](https://git-for-windows.github.io/) - it is built with the new, [properly maintained MSYS2](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25023611/3543211) and also has many new features, plenty of bug fixes and so on. There is also a 64-bit version available which would lower the chance of address space clashes considerably even if this problem was not fixed.
(info) If you're using Embedded Git, you would need to change SourceTree's Git Setting to Use System Git by navigating to Tools>Options>Git(Tab)>Git Version>Use System Git