# Why do I get memory errors when performing Git operation on Cygwin?

Tags: git, cygwin, heap-memory

I am doing Git stuff on a Cygwin bash CLI. When I perform an operation that is more than the most simple ones, I get error messages like this:

```
m.AllocationBase 0x0, m.BaseAddress 0x68570000, m.RegionSize 0x390000, m.State 0x10000
C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\cat.exe: *** Couldn't reserve space for cygwin's heap (0x68570000 <0x1210000>) in child, Win32 error 0
```

What is the cause of this error (why can't it allocate the memory) and how do I eliminate it?

When performing the operations from the TortoiseGit GUI, I have no such problems. The above quote is for a `cat` command failure as a part of `git rebase master`, but I had the same thing for `mv` during `git rebase --abort`.

**Update 1**: seems like I jumped to the "duplicate" conclusion too fast. Although the problem did not occur immediately after the 1st system restart, it later on came up again. After another restart cycle, I now get the problem even on the 1st `rebase` attempt. Thus, the question is still open:

```
$ git rebase master
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
m.AllocationBase 0x0, m.BaseAddress 0x68570000, m.RegionSize 0x4A0000, m.State 0x10000
C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\cat.exe: *** Couldn't reserve space for cygwin's heap (0x68570000 <0x1280000>) in child, Win32 error 0
C:\Program Files (x86)\Git/libexec/git-core\git-am: line 659: test: : integer expression expected
```

**Update 2**: After reading [Yirkha](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31970708/274579)'s answer to the same question, I was able to resolve the problem on my machine.

Comment: After restaring the system as suggested in the other quetsion, the problem is now gone.

Comment: Not gone, after all...