# Couldn't reserve space for cygwin's heap, Win32 error 0

Tags: batch-file, cmd, windows-10, cygwin

I'm trying to run a `.bat` file from terminal and it gives the error below. I use to open the file without any issue and don't know what causing this issue. I tried restarting my PC but it still isn't working

`0 [main] us 0 init_cheap: VirtualAlloc pointer is null, Win32 error 487
AllocationBase 0x0, BaseAddress 0x607A0000, RegionSize 0x220000, State 0x10000
C:\mozilla-build\msys\bin\bash.exe: *** Couldn't reserve space for cygwin's heap, Win32 error 0`

Comment: Your tagged this with mercurial. I do not see anything related to mercurial. I did do a quick google search ( less than a minute) and found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18502999/git-extensions-win32-error-487-couldnt-reserve-space-for-cygwins-heap-win32/31970708#31970708. It appears to be a Cygwin issue.

Comment: I already tried everything in the post and still wasn't able to fix it.

Comment: Did you trying rebasing the DLL, or even running `rebaseall`?