# WinAVR-20100110\utils\bin\sh.exe: *** Couldn't reserve space for cygwin's heap, Win32 error 0

Tags: c, avr

make all
Building file: ../main.c
Invoking: AVR Compiler
avr-gcc -Wall -g2 -gstabs -O0 -fpack-struct -fshort-enums -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -std=gnu99 -funsigned-char -funsigned-bitfields -mmcu=atmega32 -DF_CPU=8000000UL -MMD -MP -MF"main.d" -MT"main.o" -c -o "main.o" "../main.c"
AllocationBase 0x1470000, BaseAddress 0x1520000, RegionSize 0x15000, State 0x1000
C:\WinAVR-20100110\utils\bin\sh.exe: *** Couldn't reserve space for cygwin's heap, Win32 error 0
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
"make all" terminated with exit code 2. Build might be incomplete.

22:23:49 Build Failed. 1 errors, 0 warnings. (took 151ms)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMcIJ.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ATo3k.png)

Comment: For a similar problem they say a reboot is helping: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18502999/git-extensions-win32-error-487-couldnt-reserve-space-for-cygwins-heap-win32

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.